# Why doesn't input val() change in real-time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have a basic `form` where a user selects an `option` and enters a qty. into an `input` and then a basic jquery script multiplies those numbers to get a total. The only problem though is that it doesn't update in real-time. You have to see it for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/iamjosan/4T9Wq/

```
$('.setPrice').on('change', function () {

    var s = +$(this).find('option:selected').data('price');
    var q = +$('#quantity').val();

    if (q > 1) {
        var price = s * q;
    } else {
        price = s;
    }

    $('#showPrice').val(price.toFixed(2));
});
```

**How can I get the script to update the values in real-time?**

**EDIT**

Changing the `input` value(greater than 1) after selecting an `option` results in NaN, but changing the `input` value BEFORE selecting an `option` shows the real value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `input` or `keyup`, since `change` doesn't get fired in real-time, depending on the browser:

> The `input` event fires whenever the user has modified the data of the control. 
>   The `change` event fires when the value is committed, **if that makes sense for the control, or else when the control loses focus**. In all cases, the `input` event comes before the corresponding `change` event (if any). ([source](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#event-input-change))

Also, in your specific case, you need to check the item's price from the correct element:

```
var s = +$("#size").find('option:selected').data('price');
```

Don't forget to add the `id` attribute to the correct `<select>`. Otherwise you're looking for selected options in the current element context, which might be the `<input>`.

Overall ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4T9Wq/2/)):

```
$('.setPrice').on('keyup change', function () {     
    var s = +$("#size").find('option:selected').data('price');
    var q = +$('#quantity').val();
    var price = q > 1 ? s * q : s;
    $('#showPrice').val(price.toFixed(2));
});
```

Note that I added `change`, since you usually don't use the keyboard for `<select>` (but you can do this, which is why it might be a good idea to add `keyup` to that element).

Comment: when I use `input` or `keyup`, it returns NaN

Comment: He has another error: changing the value will trigger the event for the textfield, and when calling .find("options:selected") he will get a NaN, since the input has no children.

Comment: ^changing the `input` value after selecting an `option` results in NaN, but selecting an `option` AFTER shows the real value

Comment: you gave set price for both select and input!!!. so on change fire on both select and input and "this" will be the input element not the select element

Comment: ^even if I change it to `$('select')` it doesn't update it in real-time.

Comment: That worked! I want to know why it works though, because this isn't the first time that my script does this. So when I'm using `select` and `input` elements together I should use `keyup` and `change` together?

Comment: @JosanIracheta: From my experience, always use both on every form element that you want to capture, and if you have several form elements don't use `$(this)`, since you don't know which element might be the emitting one.

Comment: And that's why you're the man with 29.9k rep. Thanks a lot. Btw, I really like that short-hand `if else`.

Answer (score 0):

update your java script to this:

```
function calculate(){
        var s = $('select.setPrice').find('option:selected').data('price');
    var q = $('#quantity').val();

    if(q > 1){
    var price = s * q;
    }
    else{
    price = s;
    }
  $('#showPrice').val(price.toFixed(2));
}   

$('select.setPrice').on('change', function () { 
calculate();  
});
$('input[name="os3"]').on('keyup',function(){
calculate();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/moussawi7/4T9Wq/4/

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out:**
http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/4T9Wq/5/

```
var p = $('.showPrice'), q= $('.quantity'), s= $('.size');

$('.setPrice').on('change', function () {
    var num = q.val(), price= s.find(':selected').data('price');
    if ((!isNaN(num))&&price) p.val(num * price);      
});
```

Simple and faster.